how to read csv file with line separator exceeding 2 chars, such as @#\n@#
I have a csv file a.csv size 1TB with contents a sample as follow:
this,is,test1@#\n@#this,is,test2@#\n@#

With perl, I would set line separator $/='@#\n@#'. How to do this with python?

I don't think you can. You'll need to pre-process the file to replace the line separators with normal \n or \r\n.

Because the content contains \n

You should use proper CSV formatting when creating the file. If a field contains a newline, it should be surrounded with quotes. Any decent CSV library will do this automatically.

FWIW, Pandas read_csv only supports 1-character line terminators.

@user26195015 1TB? Are you sure? Assuming there's some mechanism to separate the rows in the CSV, how do you intend to use the data? It seems unlikely that you'd be able to keep the entire CSV in RAM

Yes, all I can think of is to use awk or perl, split the file first, and then process it in parallel, python doesn't seem to support custom line separators
